# Selecting Geometry in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I have a need to use one layer's contents as a selection for another layers contents. example: select layer 1 which is a circle  - use that circle selection marque to select smaller objects on layer 2 that only fall within the circle selection. Of course, we've been doing this for eons in photoshop. I have the whole astute graphics suite but have not found a tool that does this yet. Any ideas?

Comment: No such thing. "Doing this for eons in photoshop" - yeah, but thats something else.

Comment: It might not be possible to exactly as you ask. But if we knew more about *why* you want to do this, there could be a better and easier way to achieve what you want. Are you just looking for a way to *mask* objects?

Comment: Masking has nothing to do with it. I need to select hundreds of objects out of hundreds more by the shape of a closed path on another layer so I can isolate them on their own layer.  Astute Graphics just came out with a new plugin called find and replace; it's getting closer to what I'm trying to do but I don't think it's quite there yet. It's pretty cool though because it can be attribute driven and searches can be organized and saved.

Comment: Illustrator's *Select > Same* and *Select > Object* is the closest thing to that I guess. Don't know if it's helpful at all. (InDesign actually has a more complex *Find/Change* for objects.)

Comment: This sounds like a classic case of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What are you trying to create? Remember that Illustrator (a vector image editor) is nothing like Photoshop (a raster image editor). It's a totally different tool, so what you've been able do in Photoshop "for eons" is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe you can. Illustrator doesn't work on "marquee selections". Like all vector applications, Illustrator is **object oriented**. "Marquee selections" are more pixel-based.

You can manually use the **Lasso Tool** to select *objects* within a given area, but I think that's as close as you'll get.

Comment: I'm quite aware of how to do it as I do it every day. The innovation needed to do this would be a code snippet to select paths within the defined area. My example was a circle but in reality it's a complex layer in a map that defines an area. It's extremely tedious  so I am hoping that some third party may have come up with a solution.

Comment: @Animapper its poissible to do this. But it requires acess to the internal outlines of shapes. So while it could be scripted, the scripted version would be slow indeed. C++ API time. (Question is how much do you need this, a illustrator extension competent developper wants to have a few grands per week of devtime)